# What is the time complexity of this solution?

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity, big-o

I understand basic time complexity, but I struggle to know when the time complexity is correlated with log. Here's my solution from the HackerRank Ice Cream Parlor question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/icecream-parlor/problem

```
def icecreamParlor(m, arr):

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for k in range(i+1, len(arr), 1):
        
            if arr[i] + arr[k] == m:
                return [i+1, k+1]
```

It's my understanding that the nested loops would normally be O(n^2); however, does that change since I'm not looping through the entire list every time on the second loop? As I'm starting from i on the inner loop, the time spent looping through it increasingly decreases. What would be the time complexity of this?

Comment: Still O(n^2) since big-Oh describes worst-case. The worst-case scenario performs n * (n/2) = (n^2)/2 iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still O(n^2). Your outer loop is doing N work while your inner loop is doing n-1 work.

If you were to write out the i and k counts per loop, you would get something like this for len(arr) = 5

```
i = 1 k = 2,3,4,5
i = 2 k = 3,4,5
i = 3 k = 4,5
i = 4 k = 5
i = 5
```

This pattern of for loops resembles a Triangular number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). From the article the way to find the triangle number for any given N is N + 1 choose 2. This gives us the formula N(N+1)/2. Asymptotically this function gives us O(n^2) behavior

Answer (score 4):

At the top level, you're looping `N` times. For each `i` of those loops, you're looping some `M = N-i` times. Notice that this means that `M` averages to half of N: `(5+4+3+2+1+0) == (5+5+5+5+5)/2`. So the overall time complexity is `O(N * N/2)`, which is equivalent to `O(N*N)` or `O(N**2)`.

Comment: @OP For additional information you might also wanna have a look at [gaussian summation](https://letstalkscience.ca/educational-resources/backgrounders/gauss-summation).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [Big-O](https://pypi.org/project/big-O/) python lib!
You just need to import it and you can run your code inside it :)
This will help you in several projects.
Keep up the grind!

Comment: Also recommend Freecodecamps [Big O course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mo4vesaut8g).

Answer (score 2):

It's still O(n^2) - it's obviously gonna be faster than 2 nested loops that have n iterations each but you still have 2 loops that are variable-dependent. If you have any more questions lmk :)